# Suggestions for transparent material

Tags: materials

I am looking for a highly transparent material that is available to buy in 0.1 mm thick film/sheets.

The only one I am aware of is PMMA (aka plexiglass) but I haven't been able to locate a supplier of such thin plates/film.

Do you have any other suggestions? (It does not have to be particularly strong, but highly transparent)

Comment: -1 because I believe this is borderline with our "shopping advice" policy. See the [meta discussion](http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/q/607/2196) for more details about our product recommendation policy.

Comment: 0.1mm is impossibly thin for anything that's not just an adhesive glass covering or anything. You'll have a lot more options if you can tolerate greater thickness.

Answer (score 2):

If you are good with "film" there are many options - mylar (polyester), whatever grocery store plastic wrap is, heat shrink window film (polyolefin, perhaps?)

If 50x75mm is sufficient size (you didn't specify), #1 microscope cover glass (thus - glass) is 0.13-0.17mm thick, and is available (at least) that large.

4 mil (0.004") is a pretty typical thickness for overhead transparencies, available at any office supply store. That's almost exactly 0.1mm.